# Jquery not working when I import another version of thath in wordpress functions.php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquerymin', get_theme_file_uri('/js/jquery.min.js'), NULL,'3.4.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('owl', get_theme_file_uri('/js/owl.carousel.min.js'), NULL, '4.3', true);
wp_enqueue_script('script', get_theme_file_uri('/js/script.js'), Null, '2.3.4',true);
```

I use jquery 3.4.1 for owl carousel in my website. but I have another slider plugin 'soliloquy'. When I dregister older version of jquery, the plugin goes in loading mode.
[image]

what should I do now?

Comment: can you share a URL

Comment: I develop my theme locally. There is no url to share

Comment: comment
 wp_enqueue_script('jquerymin', get_theme_file_uri('/js/jquery.min.js'), NULL,'3.4.1', true);

wp_deregister_script('jquery');

Comment: I know it. but if I comment those lines, owl carousel script failed in my theme. Minimum compatible jQuery version for owl  is 1.8.3 version

Comment: Did you try registering jquerymin as a dependancy of owl?

Comment: I try almost any ways but I don't know why the plugin goes in loading mode!!